# Passing commands to deployed Ruby on Rails App in Bluemix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ibm-cloud

Finally, with the help of SO member, [JeffSloyer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3817025/jeff-sloyer), I was able to deploy my RoR app on to bluemix. There seems to be an additional problem with the RoR app. I cant login as admin in this app.

http://csw-events.mybluemix.net/sign_in

The question here is not about the app itself, I have found a solution from the forum dedicated to this RoR app(Currently, in-active) -> [SOLUTION](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openconferenceware/bT-S84ZxXmI).

The question is
1: Can I pass commands to an already deployed app on Bluemix using **CF** something like this

```
 cf -c "User.last.update_attribute(:admin, true)"
```

If not, What are the alternatives for passing such commands

As for this eg it is

```
bundle exec rails console
User.last.update_attribute(:admin, true)
```

Comment: Have you looked into SSHing to the server (via e.g. https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/07/16/easy-ssh-sessions-bluemix/) and running the command that way? The CF API doesn't seem to support easily running arbitrary commands.

Comment: @RobertNubel, I tried using the procedure as shown in the blog. Unfortunately, it throws an error  `Running: ssh  y5A0ahaaaaaaaaaaaauaPO@ny1.tmate.io
Permission denied (publickey).
Deleting app abcd-ssh in org abcd@gmail.com / space abcd as abcd@gmail.com…`

Comment: Do you have an SSH key on your local machine? [This issue](https://github.com/nviennot/tmate/issues/24) suggests that might be the problem. If you don't, and you're on Windows, download Putty and run putty-keygen. If you're on Mac or Linux, run the `ssh-keygen` command from terminal.

Comment: You can not ssh into a Bluemix CF application.

Comment: I did use the `cf-ssh` to enter the bluemix. But, ur right, as u suggested in the answer below, it doesn't work on a already running application.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass commands to an already running CF application.

You can have the buildpack run commands for you at the start of the application by creating a manifest.yml file at the root of your application and specifying the command.

Sample manifest.yml:

```
---
applications:
- name: my-rails-app
  command: bundle exec rake cf:on_first_instance db:migrate && bundle exec rails s -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV
```

[Tips for Ruby Developers](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/ruby/ruby-tips.html#rake)

Answer (score 0):

You could also push the app again and add a command with the -c option:

```
cf push -f manifest.yml -c "User.last.update_attribute(:admin, true)"
```

It would mean some downtime but only a very limited amount of time.

If the app does not run anymore with a consequent push, run the same cf command with -c "null", Cloud Foundry is a bit buggy that way.

If it is only a once off command you want to pass this would be the recommended way, instead of putting it in the manifest file.